# move AngularJS site to Google Cloud environment

Tags: angularjs, node.js, google-cloud-platform

I have the project created in AngularJS with node.js web server which I run locally on my computer. I would like to move this AngularJS project to Google Cloud environment. I created Google Cloud free account for this but it is not clear for me what exactly I suppose to do next to move my AngularJS project there.

I found some links but not sure that this is what i am looking for : https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/run-on-compute-engine
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/angularjs-cloud-endpoints-recipe-for-building-modern-web-applications#combining-angularjs-with-cloud-endpoints

Is somebody have already move his AngularJS project to Google Cloud and created web services for that project on Google Cloud environment?
If so, could you please give some links and describe steps which suppose to be done for that?
Thank you

Comment: Did you follow the tutorial for node.js ?

Comment: for node.js not, I did just for java, maybe I was wrong. I will try for node.js Thank you

Comment: Please do; all you need is that tutorial for start.

Comment: Locally I am running my AngularJS site with http-server <path to site directory> commant. I tried to move my AngularJS project same way like it described in node.js tutorial, I created manually in my AngularJS site directory app.yaml file with content :                                                        # [START app_yaml]
runtime: nodejs
vm: true
# [END app_yaml]

Comment: but when I run : "gcloud app deploy" command from my site directory I receive : WARNING: Deployment of App Engine Flexible Environment apps is currently in Beta
ERROR: node.js checker: No npm start and no server.js
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Your application does not satisfy all of the requirements for a runtime of type [nodejs].  Please correct the errors and try again.

Comment: You have to deploy a full fledged app. app.yaml will be in the root folder where your server.js for node.js is placed. And within that directory you might have a directory called public or views etc for your front end content.

Comment: But I don't have server.js for node.js file. I am running my AngularJS application locally by running http-server <path to site directory> command. Example : http-server C:\AngularJS\test_angular . I am using http-server command https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server . How can I create or configure server.js file?

Comment: just make a simple node.js server file then, I hope you know that.

Comment: could you please provide an example, because I tried to use http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_web_module.htm server.js from that link but it still doesn't work? thank you

Comment: Full Solution posted as answer take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is what you are supposed to do and I hope it will help you.

This is what your directory listing should look like.

[image: Directory App Engine]

In the public folder all my frontend codes are there. HTML pages, css, js files and everything else is there only in proper format as expected.

Ignore the routes etc. and I have deleted folder names that weren't required in your case.

Now I presume you know how to configure app.yaml and package.json because you have gone through the tutorial. If not, please go through it once again, the Package.json part and app.yaml configuration part.

This is what your are supposed to write in `app.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/indexz.html');
});

app.listen(1339);
console.log('Open this link http://localhost:1337');
```

NOTE : The public in above code is the folder that contains your frontend part.

The `indexz.html` is name of the homepage, change it according to what you need.

Now, deploy this to your server and if everything goes right when you open the appsoft link your index page will open up and everything will work as it works for you on your localhost.

Best of luck.

Comment: Sure mate, let me know if it works or not. It should work if things fall in place. Cloud Environment in the beginning seems tricky but it'll be better with time.

Comment: I believe that it something with configuration that I selected for Google Cloud (Linux Ubuntu) and my local environment (Windows 10). Ever google seed project https://github.com/angular/angular-seed runs on my local but when I run gcloud app deploy it return that  "unknown command -> bower install". I gonna install virtual machine with Ubuntu and try to run google seed first and then my project from Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: You are using bower for angular? If yes, how about keeping the modules already there in public folder where your frontend content is. Use Package.json for your backend's modules and app.yaml should be configured properly.

Comment: Thank you, right now I cannot continue configuration my project but I checked you answer like correct because I think I pretty close to deploy my project on google cloud. Please let me know if I can do something for you to show my gratitude.

Comment: I was just taking special interest in this because I was confused myself when I started cloud deployment mate. Let me know if you face any problems. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get your Node.js app hosted on Google Cloud Platform is on App Engine Flex. Take a look at a Hello World sample here:

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world

Once you go through that, it should be obvious how to move your own Node.js app.

Comment: Locally I am running my AngularJS site with http-server <path to site directory> commant. I tried to move my AngularJS project same way like it described in https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world tutorial, I created manually in my AngularJS site directory app.yaml file with content : # [START app_yaml] runtime: nodejs vm: true # [END app_yaml]

Comment: but when I run : "gcloud app deploy" command from my site directory I receive : WARNING: Deployment of App Engine Flexible Environment apps is currently in Beta ERROR: node.js checker: No npm start and no server.js ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Your application does not satisfy all of the requirements for a runtime of type [nodejs]. Please correct the errors and try again.